# Primefaces 6.1 p:editor or p:textEditor

Tags: primefaces

I'm a just a beginner in JSF and primefaces framework. Since p:editor in  Primefaces 6.1 is deprecated, can I continue using it instead of p:textEditor because I like the existing design.

Would it be any impact to my other forms ?

Comment: Yes you can, but be aware that if they depracated it, it means it will be removed in newer releases. So as long as you don't upgrade primefaces to a version that this component was not removed you can keep using it.

Comment: As PrimeFaces also releases security fixes with new versions, I would not go with deprecated components. Especially not is it's just for the looks. If you want customisation, have a look at https://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/ckEditor/basicUsage.jsf

Comment: Thanks for the info.